# Why Locale.current.regionCode is nil?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I am trying to get user's region code in swift 3 by using:

```
Locale.current.regionCode
```

Unfortunately regionCode is nil, do you have an idea why?
And what should I do to obtain it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: We will need more details. What is the current language and region set to in the settings? What does `Locale.current.identifier` say? Are you on a device or a simulator? Give us as much detail as you can think of and what all things you have looked at.

Comment: I am on device. 

In device settings I set:  Language = "French" ; Region = "Canada"
I obtain : Locale.current.identifier = "fr"

Comment: @thierryb Hey anything would you share it with me ?
Facing same problem!

Comment: I have the same issue on Simulator when setting the region to Germany and the language to US English. Locale.current is `en` and regionCode is nil... Worked in Xcode <=10

Answer (score 26):

For those looking for solutions at **SIMULATOR**, go to "Settings > General > Language & Region" and change the region.

It worked for me and other people.
For a weird unknown reason, some simulators doesn't return the region until it changes at least once.

I don't know if it works at real device as well, because I did not had this problem on real device.

Comment: @Heckscheibe did it worked at real device? If anyone solved this problem on real device, let us know, please. Then I can update the answer :)

Comment: no, it only fixed it on the simulator, I did not have this issue on a real device...

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same issue and as it turns out it was because I set my Scheme to a specific language. If you set both, Application Language & Application Region to "System Language / Region" it should work.

[image]

Comment: I just tried this and region code is always nil no matter what I pick for region.

Comment: For me the regionCode was always nil in Xcode 11. On my collegues machine this doesn't happen though but they all have the same settings in Xcode. I have no idea why I get this behavior all the time. It bubbeled up due to one unit test we have.

Comment: @blackjacx do you use simulator or real device?

Comment: @EduardoHerzer I use the simulator. On [device | CI | colleques simulator] it doesn't happen :(

Comment: @blackjacx In simulator, go to "Settings > General > Language & Region" and change the region. It worked for me. For a weird unknown reason, some simulators doesn't return the region until it changes at least once

Comment: @EduardoHerzer You should put your comment as an answer to the question for those working on the simulator that did the trick!

Comment: @nunoh123 did it. I hope it helps other people

Answer (score 2):

Many of the properties on Locale can return nil for various reasons on iOS (and Android).

You may also use `objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode` to query the country code.

```
// code may be nil
NSString *code = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
```

It's a good idea to have a fallback logic to find countryCode with CoreTelephony.

```
CTCarrier *carrier = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new] subscriberCellularProvider];
NSString *countryCode = carrier.isoCountryCode;
```

Or/And with reverse geocode:

```
// CLLocationManagerDelegate
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {
    __block CLLocation *location = [locations firstObject];

    [[[CLGeocoder alloc] init] reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray<CLPlacemark *> * _Nullable placemarks, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error && placemarks.count > 0) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks firstObject];
            // Use placemark.country;
            // Use placemark.ISOCountryCode;
        }
    }
}
```

For instance, on Android version of corresponding region query for Locale, it's nil for many of the rooted devices.

Comment: `Locale.regionCode === NSLocale.countryCode === (Locale.current as NSLocale).object(forKey: .countryCode)`, see https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/Locale.swift#L154-L165

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for regionCode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2293371-regioncode) states

> The region code of the locale, or nil if it has none.

Some locales simply do not have a region (aka country) code. However I don't know which ones do not.