# iOS user with language of "en", no region code, translation lookup fails

Tags: ios, localization, locale, nslocalizedstring

We have a bug reported where a user has a device with an `en` language and `nil` region code, and thus all `NSLocalizedString` lookups in are failing, meaning our string key is what is rendered onscreen. Thus, if we had this in our `en.lproj/Localizable.strings` file:

`"some_key" = "Some string.";`

It would render `some_key` instead of `Some string.` in our UI.

First question: how do I replicate this scenario locally? [This question on Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635555/why-locale-current-regioncode-is-nil) seems to almost describe the issue, but does not describe how one enters this state.

Second question: why would iOS not fall back to English in the event the region code was `nil`?

Answer (score 0):

> Second question: why would iOS not fall back to English in the event
> the region code was nil?

The cause can be "There is no base development language that is enabled". Or it is iOS logic.

Here is my solution for **Localization**. I just want to share with you an alternative solution if it can help you to solve the issue.

```
public enum AppResourceLang: String {
    case en
    case vi
}

public class AppResManager {
    public static let shared = AppResManager()
    public var lang = "en"
    var textBundle: Bundle!
    
    public var mainBundle: Bundle!
    
    private init() {

        let mainBundleId = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
        // we use mainBundle's bundleIdentifier because normally your running target will contains "lproj" in Copy Bundle Resource
        // If your text/image is located on different project/target or framework, you need to enter that target's bundleId.
    
        mainBundle = Bundle(identifier: mainBundle)!
        let path = mainBundle.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj")
        textBundle = Bundle(path: path!)
    }
    
    public func changeLang(code: String) {
        if let path = mainBundle.path(forResource: code, ofType: "lproj") {
            lang = code; textBundle = Bundle(path: path)
        } else {
            // fallback to English
            lang = "en"
            let path = mainBundle.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj")
            textBundle = Bundle(path: path!)
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can use above `textBundle` like below:

```
public extension String {    
    var localText: String {
        guard let bundle = AppResManager.shared.textBundle else { return self }
        return NSLocalizedString(self, bundle: bundle, comment: "")
    }
    
    var lTextUpcased: String {
        guard let bundle = AppResManager.shared.textBundle else { return self.uppercased() }
        return NSLocalizedString(self, bundle: bundle, comment: "").uppercased()
    }
}
```

Here is my AppResource (like a framework). We can see I have `Localizable.strings` and it is localized for EN, VI.
[image: Here is my AppResource (like a framework)]

Here is the real file/folder structure, you can see if you check on English in Localization for *.string, *.storyboard,... file. It will be cloned and saved in this folder (ex: en.lproj). You can base on this to point to the corresponding resource file.

[image]

Then, how to use my above codes. It is just a way to allow you to completely control the Localization.

```
    public enum AppLanguage: String {
        case en
        case vi
    }

    // MARK: - Device info
    public static func getDeviceLang() -> AppLanguage {
        guard let languageCode = Locale.current.languageCode else { return .en }
        let appLang = AppLanguage(rawValue: languageCode.lowercased()) ?? .en
        return appLang
    }

    // Then this will switch the language of your resource based on device language.
    AppResManager.shared.changeLang(code: YourGlobalClass.getDeviceLang().rawValue)

    // Then use the above string extension to load the corresponding text
    // Anywhere in your project.
    let text = "your_key".localText
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet. How do you test it?

Comment: @esilver I updated my answer, please check it for how to use it and the reason why I can make it.